# Calling an objects' members using cin to get object name

Tags: c++, oop, object, user-input

I am trying to find a way to call an object's members, but using a user input to determine which object. So, I have 3 objects: obj1, obj2, obj3. I then ask a user to enter which object they want to manipulate. Then using this input, I call the respective object's member function.

```
string input;
cin >> input; 
input.memberfunc();//where input is obj1, for example
```

I understand that this is obviously not the way, and that I would firstly have to convert the string etc., but would appreciate any advise on the best way to achieve my requirement.

Comment: There is nothing built in for this. You have to code it yourself, like `if (input == "obj1") obj1.memberfunc();`, etc.

Comment: You could use a std::map.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array of objects

```
Object *objects[3] = {&obj1, &obj2, &obj3};
int index;
cin >> index;
if ((index > 0) && (index < 4))
{
   object[index]->memberfunc();
}
```

or if you want to select by string, you can do it using map;

```
std::map<std::string, Object *> objectmap;
objectmap["obj1"] = &obj1;
objectmap["obj2"] = &obj2;
objectmap["obj3"] = &obj3;
std::string input;
cin >> input;
if (objectmap.find(input) != objectmap.end())
{
    objectmap[input]->memberfunc();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps. Although, could I still use this method if I wish to add more objects if required. The purpose of the question is to be able to create a library catalogue system whereby the objects are books. Then the user is asked to input a name of the book to be borrowed and then call a book1.borrowed(); function. However, there also has to be the possibility to add more books to the catalogue. Using the method you gave, would I have to redefine the array every time I extended the catalogue?

Comment: The second way that @V-X show (using a map) allow you to dynamically add any object (I will post the code as answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as V-X suggested. Calling `objectmap["objn"] = &objn` inserts a new element, if "objn" does not match the key of any already existing element in the container.

You could also use `map::insert`:

`objectmap.insert( std::pair<std::string,Object*>( "objn", &objn ));`

Here's a link for more details on [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

Answer (score 0):

Using @V-X answer to dynamically add books:

```
std::map<std::string, Book* > bookmap;
bookmap["obj1"] = &obj1;
bookmap["obj2"] = &obj2;
bookmap["obj3"] = &obj3;

//Dynamically loaded book:    
Book* newBook = new Book(/* any arguments you need */);
bookmap[ newBook->getIdentifier() ] = newBook;

std::string input;
cin >> input;
if (bookmap.find(input) != bookmap.end())
{
    bookmap[input]->bookmap();
} else {
    cerr << "Error: book '" << input << "' not found." << endl;
}
```